# Hostname Error001 Description error message on mac osx when i connect to xampp

Tags: macos, xampp

I can't seem to connect to xampp on my machine. I get this error message HostnameError001Description. I have tried fixing it with this solution http://www.techyv.com/questions/xampp-hostname-error-001-description but this does not seem to work. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 1):

Did you make any changes to security?

I got the same error after i tried to change some things by doing: sudo /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/xampp security

The fix was to run again: sudo /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/xampp security

The prompt ask for answer in German so put "nein" (no in english) for the prompt.

Quite XAMPP and try again.

Workaround if the above does not work:
sudo /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/xampp start
sudo /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/xampp stop

For me the XMAPP app worked fine after few attempts.